# How do I know if instance is ready to be invoked?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I wrote the following code to launch the `AWS Instance`. It works fine. I am able to launch `AWS` instance. But I need to wait, until the instance's status check is `2/2` or the instance is ready to be invoked.

```
public function launch_instance() {
    $isInstanceLaunched = array('status' => false);
    try {
        if(!empty($this->ec2Client)) {
            /**
             * 1) EbsOptimized : Indicates whether the instance is optimized for EBS I/O. 
             * This optimization provides dedicated throughput to Amazon EBS and an optimized 
             * configuration stack to provide optimal EBS I/O performance. This optimization isn't 
             * available with all instance types. Additional usage charges apply when using an 
             * EBS-optimized instance.
             */
            $result = $this->ec2Client->runInstances([
                    'AdditionalInfo' => 'Launched from API',
                    'DisableApiTermination' => false,
                    'ImageId' => 'ami-8xaxxxe8', // REQUIRED
                    'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior' => 'stop',
                    'InstanceType' => 't2.micro',
                    'MaxCount' => 1, // REQUIRED
                    'MinCount' => 1, // REQUIRED,
                    'EbsOptimized' => false, // SEE COMMENT 1
                    'KeyName' => 'TestCloudKey',
                    'Monitoring' => [
                            'Enabled' => true // REQUIRED
                    ],
                    'SecurityGroups' => ['TestGroup']
            ]);

            if($result) {
                $metadata = $result->get('@metadata');
                $statusCode = $metadata['statusCode'];
                //Verify if the code is 200
                if($statusCode == 200) {
                    $instanceData = $result->get('Instances');
                    $instanceID = $instanceData[0]['InstanceId'];
                    // Give  a name to the launched instance
                    $tagCreated = $this->ec2Client->createTags([
                            'Resources' => [$instanceID],
                            'Tags' => [
                                    [
                                            'Key' => 'Name',
                                            'Value' => 'Created from API'
                                    ]
                            ]
                    ]);
                    $instance = $this->ec2Client->describeInstances([
                            'InstanceIds' => [$instanceID]
                    ]);
                    $instanceInfo = $instance->get('Reservations')[0]['Instances'];
                    // Get the Public IP of the instance
                    $instancePublicIP = $instanceInfo[0]['PublicIpAddress'];
                    // Get the Public DNS of the instance
                    $instancePublicDNS = $instanceInfo[0]['PublicDnsName'];
                    // Get the instance state
                    $instanceState = $instanceInfo[0]['State']['Name'];
                    $instanceS = $this->ec2Client->describeInstanceStatus([
                            'InstanceIds' => [$instanceID]
                    ]);
                    try {
                        $waiterName = 'InstanceRunning';
                        $waiterOptions = ['InstanceId' => $instanceID];
                        $waiter = $this->ec2Client->getWaiter($waiterName,$waiterOptions);
                        // Initiate the waiter and retrieve a promise.
                        $promise = $waiter->promise();
                        // Call methods when the promise is resolved.
                        $promise
                        ->then(function () {
                            // Waiter Completed
                        })
                        ->otherwise(function (\Exception $e) {
                            echo "Waiter failed: " . $e . "\n";
                        });
                        // Block until the waiter completes or fails. Note that this might throw
                        // a RuntimeException if the waiter fails.
                        $promise->wait();
                    }catch(RuntimeException $runTimeException) {
                        $isInstanceLaunched['side-information'] = $runTimeException->getMessage();
                    }   
                    $isInstanceLaunched['aws-response'] = $result;
                    $isInstanceLaunched['instance-public-ip'] = $instancePublicIP;
                    $isInstanceLaunched['status'] = true;
                }   
            }               
        }else {
            $isInstanceLaunched['message'] = 'EC2 client not initialized. Call init_ec2 to initialize the client';
        }
    }catch(Ec2Exception $ec2Exception){
        $isInstanceLaunched['message'] = $ec2Exception->getMessage().'-- FILE --'.$ec2Exception->getFile().'-- LINE --'.$ec2Exception->getLine();
    }catch(Exception $exc) {
        $isInstanceLaunched['message'] = $exc->getMessage().'-- FILE -- '.$exc->getFile().'-- LINE -- '.$exc->getLine();
    }

    return $isInstanceLaunched;
}
```

I have used the `waiter` named `InstanceRunning` but that doesn't help. How do I know that the instance is ready to be invoked or the status check is `2/2`?

Answer (score 1):

have you try to replace

```
$waiter = $this->ec2Client->getWaiter($waiterName,$waiterOptions);
```

with

```
$this->ec2Client->waitUntil($waiterName, $waiterOptions);          
$result = $ec2->describeInstances(array(
                'InstanceIds' => array($instanceId),
            ));
```

I did not test for some time but it used to work for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two waiters: first "InstanceRunning" and then  "InstanceStatusOk"

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment, This was exactly my problem

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code to check if the instance is ready to be invoked. I do a `polling` to check if the `statusCheck` is `ok`.

```
    /**
     * The following block checks if the instance is ready to be invoked
     * or StatusCheck of the instance equals 2/2
     * Loop will return:
     *  - If the status check received is 'ok'
     *  - If it exceeds _amazon_client::MAX_ATTEMPTS_TO_EC2_SCHECK
     */

    $statusCheckAttempt = 0;
    do {
        // Sleep for _amazon_client::POLLING_SECONDS
        sleep(_amazon_client::POLLING_SECONDS);
        // Query the instance status
        $instanceS = $this->ec2Client->describeInstanceStatus([
                'InstanceIds' => [$instanceID]
        ]);
        $statusCheck = $instanceS->get('InstanceStatuses')[0]['InstanceStatus']['Status'];
        $statusCheckAttempt++;
    }while($statusCheck != 'ok' || 
            $statusCheckAttempt >= _amazon_client::MAX_ATTEMPTS_TO_EC2_SCHECK);
```

**Note**: When the instance has just been launched,  `$instanceS->get('InstanceStatuses')[0]` returns an empty array. So I wait some seconds, before I could actually get the status.

Please suggest if there are better methods to achieve this.